# How do put multiple values into a single key in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Is there a way to put multiple values in one key in Swift's dictionary, such as 'multimap' in Java?

`var multiDic = [String:UserData]()`

This is the dictionary I declared. it has this structure.

```
struct UserData{
    var name: String
    var id: String
    var nickname: String
}
```

And when I put the value in one key in the dictionary, the value is updated without being stacked.

```
for key in 1...10 {
    multiDic.updateValue(UserData(name:"name+\(key)", id:"id+\(key)", nickname:"nick+\(key)"), forKey: "A")
}
```

`print(multiDic.count)`

**reults**
1

How can I accumulate multiple values on a single key? I looked up a library called 'Buckets'
(https://github.com/mauriciosantos/Buckets-Swift#buckets), but there has been no update since swift 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift dictionary doesn't support this. One work around is to declare the dictionary to hold an array of values, like this:

```
var multiDic = [String:[UserData]]()
```

You would have to modify your code for adding values to work with the array instead of updating the value in place.

I haven't tried the "Buckets" project you mention, but for what it's worth, it probably still works either as-is or with minor changes.

Comment: It's worth noting that the syntax `multiDic[key, default: []].append(newValue)` will come in handy.

Comment: Thank you. I totally understand. I'm going to use "Buckets".